# how to approach <a href ="" class=""> by using find() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to add **on**Class in a tag
and also  by using jQuery event.
I try to approach  by using find(). is it right like that coding?  please, how to resolve this problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab_cont, .on').each(function(){
    var topDiv = $('.tab_cont, .on');  
    var anchors = topDiv.find('ui .screen1 a');
    var panelDivs = topDiv.find('div.area_cont, div');

    var lastAnchor;
    var lastPanel;
    lastAnchor = anchors.filter('.on');
    lastPanel = panelDivs.filter('.on');
  
    anchors.show();  

    anchors.click(function(event) {  
      event.preventDefault();
      var currentAnchor = $(this);
      currentAnchor.addClass("on");
      lastAnchor.removeClass("on");
      lastAnchor = currentAnchor;
      //lastPanel=currentAnchor;
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_cont on">
     <ul class="theater_zone screen1">
      <li class="area0001">
       <span class="area_zone"> 
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="on">
   <h4>tab1(<em>23</em>)</h4>
   <div class="blind">select</div>
  </a></span>
   <div class="area_cont on">
  <ul class="area_list d0001">
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011013">panel1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011018">panel1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100019010">panel1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011004">panel1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011009">panel1</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
    </li>
 <li class="area0002"><span class="area_zone">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
           <h4>tab2(<em>40</em>)</h4>
     </a></span>
   <div class="area_cont">
    <ul class="area_list d0002">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023015">panel2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023030">panel2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023027">panel2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

it doesn't work. I try to approach  by using find(). is it right like that coding?..  please, how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry body can't understand your question.
Do you want to add Class attribute using JQuery ?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER he want add `class="on"` to `<a>` tag

Comment: A couple of problems. Your selectors could be re-written to be clearer and the click event could be moved out of the scope of the each loop. What are you trying to do? When you click any link you need to know which parent UL it is in and then add the "on" class to that anchor?

Comment: @kwangkyu my advice, replace `javascript:void(0);` with `javascript:;` for less writen

Comment: What is the each() supposed to be doing?

Comment: for the details, when I press tab2, It should  add  class=on in a and div.area_cont. but it didin't.

Comment: and already tried the code javascript:;.. it didn't work..

Comment: You have many many problems in your code. The declaration of your variables doesn't make sense. Why declare `var topDiv = $('.tab_cont, .on');` after the each function? and not before ? and if you declare it after, why don't you declare it as `var topDiv = $(this)` , because it seems you are reffering to the same elements that have the each function attached .  And this is just one. I suggest you look better at your code and rethink your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would simplify your selectors and make the click event independent of the other handlers.

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $("a").removeClass("on");
  $(this).addClass("on");

});
```

You can remove the classes before adding the new one to simplify your code. No need to traverse the whole dom using find() when you can just clear them all.

If you can provide more explanation as to what you are trying to do beyond just adding a class, I can help more.

Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("span.area_zone a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //remove tab css
    $("span.area_zone a").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $(this).parent().parent().find('div.area_cont').addClass("on");

  });

  $(".area_list a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //remove panel css
    $(".area_list a").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
    
    //update the tab
    $("span.area_zone a").removeClass("on");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('span.area_zone a').addClass("on");
  });

});
```

```css
span.area_zone a.on { color:red;}
.area_list a.on { color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_cont on">
  <ul class="theater_zone screen1">
    <li class="area0001">
      <span class="area_zone"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="on">
        <h4>tab1(<em>23</em>)</h4>
        <div class="blind">select</div>
    </a></span>
      <div class="area_cont on">
        <ul class="area_list d0001">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011013">panel1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011018">panel1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100019010">panel1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011004">panel1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100011009">panel1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="area0002"><span class="area_zone">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">
       <h4>tab2(<em>40</em>)</h4>
 </a></span>
      <div class="area_cont">
        <ul class="area_list d0002">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023015">panel2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023030">panel2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="100023027">panel2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful for me. additionally when I press  tab1 and then press panel1,   can state(tab1) of being pressed be maintained ?

Comment: I've modified the answer. I've used parent().parent() to go up two levels in the context of the anchor click. Tell me more about maintaining the state. Yes, it is possible but I'm still not quite clear what you need yet.

Comment: for the detail, tab1(pressed) stay with red and then when I press  any panel1, should not influence on tab1.

Comment: and next problem is when I press tab2, this.area_cont class is add 'on'class and last.area_cont is removed 'on'class

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. I have changed the above snippet so that if you click a panel, it updates the tab too. If you click just the tab, the tab is only updated. I broke out the click events into separate handlers. You can use parent() to traverse up and find() to go back down the dom tree.

Comment: Thank you so much. I resolve it by your help. I first asked the problem on Stackoverflow today. I'm satisfied because It's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here, I'm thinking there is a much cleaner solution to what your trying to do, but I wanted to try to help you out.

Here are some slight modifications to your JavaScript that may help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab_cont.on').each(function() {
        var topDiv = $(this);
        var anchors = topDiv.find('.area_zone > a');
        anchors.show();
        anchors.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var currentAnchor = $(this);
            if(currentAnchor.is('.on')) {
                topDiv.find('.area_zone > a:not(.on)').addClass('on');
                currentAnchor.removeClass('on');
            } else {
                topDiv.find('.area_zone > a.on').removeClass('on');
                currentAnchor.addClass('on');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also created a [JSFiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/us2ayqzL/) for you to play with if you'd like as well.